# Best way to create private and public feed

Tags: getstream-io

I am a novice in `getStream.io` and I want that every user of my application get a private feed where he will find his activities, and he get a public feed where he will find his activities and friend's activities.

To do it, I created one feed (the private one) for each user in the group `user` then I added activities to their feed.

After for each user I created a feed (the public ones) in the group `timeline` and this feed follows the user associated to see his activities in the public feed (like Facebook, Instagram, Twitter...).

I researched a lot on the community to know if it is the best way to do private and public feed for each user but I read it was bad to follow himself in his timeline. I put my code here :`

```
# Initialize the client with your api key and secret
client = stream.connect('YOUR_API_KEY', 'API_KEY_SECRET')
# For the feed group 'user' and user id 'user1' get the feed
user1_feed = client.feed('user', 'user1') #User1's feed
# Add the activity to the feed
user1_feed.add_activity({'actor': 'user1', 'verb': 'tweet', 'object': "user1a1", 'tweet': 'Hello world It s me user1', 'likes': 0})  #user1a1
user1_feed.add_activity({'actor': 'user1', 'verb': 'watch', 'object': "user1a2", 'youtube_id': 'W9GvhL53nyw', 'likes': 0})        #user1a2

# The same with 'user2'
user2_feed = client.feed('user', 'user2') #User1's feed
user2_feed.add_activity({'actor': 'user2', 'verb': 'tweet', 'object': "user2a1", 'tweet': 'Hello world It s me user2', 'likes': 0})  #user2a1
user2_feed.add_activity({'actor': 'user2', 'verb': 'watch', 'object': "user2a2", 'youtube_id': 'PoxLSUh7pYw', 'likes': 0})        #user2a2

user1_timeline = client.feed('timeline', 'user1') #User1's timeline
user2_timeline = client.feed('timeline', 'user2') #User2's timeline

user1_timeline.follow('user','user1') #user1_timeline follows user1
user1_timeline.follow('user','user2') #user1_timeline follows user2

user2_timeline.follow('user','user2') #user2_timeline follows user2
user2_timeline.follow('user','user1') #user2_timeline follows user1
```

`

And I don't want to create duplicates, if I understand the Documentation, the group timeline just display.

So I would like to know if my method was the best way to create private and public feed.

Thanks!
Pierre.

Comment: When you say "private feed" do you perhaps mean that the feed contains only the activities created and added by a specific user; perhaps more clearly described as a "personal feed"? Or are you looking for a situation where a user may create either "private" activities (only visible to that user) and "public" activities (which will appear in other users' feeds)?

Comment: When I say "private feed" I want to say "personal feed" where you see only your activities and where you can add new activities. "Public feed" is a feed where I can see my activities and the activities of my friends (friends that I followed). sorry for the ambiguity :)

Comment: No problem - just wanted to be clear in order to give the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is spot on and the sample looks correct and will behave as you've described.

The `user1` feed will contain only the "personal" activities of User 1. Your application may restrict access, such that only User 1 can if your features and UX calls for it. The activities aren't 'private' as they may have been copied into other users' `user_timeline` feeds if there is a following relationship.

The `user1_timeline` feed will combine the activities that User 1 added to their `user` feed (due to the follow relationship created in your sample) as well as activities from other users' 'user' feeds that have been followed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Yes the activities will not be "private" because if a user follows me, he will see my activities :)